# free lightweight report component for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am quite new to asp and my question is:
what free lightweight report component for asp.net are out there.  Crystal report is not welcomed and we would like to avoid using heavy ObjectDatasource.  What sould I learn first (may be asp page life cycle) and what are time proven free analog of ReportViewer for asp is out there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience with it, but you may look at Jasper Reports.net. I have successfully used the Jasper Reports java, which is very good. See

http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports.net

http://aspalliance.com/1140